# How do I replace all urls in text with clickable 'page titles'?

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I'm looking for the right way to replace all the URLs in my text with -

`<a href=<link from the text>>PAGE TITLE OF THE LINK</a>`

That is let's say I've the following text

`I visit https://google.com, https://yahoo.com and other websites`

I want it to modify it to -

`I visit [Google][1], [Yahoo][1] and other websites`.

Would really appreciate your responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick ...

```
$text = "Google is https://google.com and Yahoo is http://yahoo.com";
$text = preg_replace('/(http[s]{0,1}\:\/\/\S{4,})\s{0,}/ims', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1 </a>', $text);
echo $text;
```

However, this is only going to create the links using the link URL as the label. To automatically handle the label side of things you will have to expand on your code depending on how you intend to use this in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following expression:

```
\bhttps?://\S+\b
```

Broken down this reads

```
\b - a word boundary
http:// or https://
\S+ - no whitespaces, as long as possible
\b - another word boundary
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/MDkGSv/2/).

---

In a second step you'd need to save the links in an array, look up every new item and assign a number to it.